# NY state tax when living in NY and working 100% remotely for a company in WA

Tags: united-states, taxes, state-income-tax, new-york

I got taxed for NY state(when residing in NY state) and working for a IT company in WA state(WA is my work state).

Notes:

1. I lived in NY for less than 184 days.

- 1 Jan 2020 - 15 March 2020 - India - 75 days
- 16 March 2020 - 15 Aug 2020 - New York - 153 days
- 16 August 2020 - 31 Dec 2020 - Washington - 138 days

As per https://www.tax.ny.gov/pit/file/pit_definitions.htm#nonresident, I do not qualify as a resident and hence can be considered as non-resident for tax purposes.

> You are a New York State resident for income tax purposes if:
>
> 1. your domicile is New York State (see Exception below); or
> 2. you maintain a permanent place of abode in New York State for substantially all of the taxable year and spend 184 days or more in
>    New York State during the taxable year, whether or not you are
>    domiciled in New York State for any portion of the taxable year. Note:
>    Any part of a day is a day for this purpose.

As per https://www.tax.ny.gov/pdf/current_forms/it/it203i.pdf#page=7

> If you were a nonresident of New York State, you are subject to New
> York State tax on income derived from New York State sources.

On the same page

Nonresidents - NY sources of income:

> services performed in New York State;

I am not entirely sure if work I have performed can be considered as services performed in NY state as I was working virtually for Washington state (my work state). W-2 mentions the same that my employer is from WA.

**Can I claim refund for all the taxed withheld by employer for NY state tax?**

Comment: During the 1 Jan to 15 March period did you still have a place to live in NY? Did you change you domicile to Washington in August? Did you get a Washington drivers license? Did you register your car there?...

Comment: I had a place to live in NY from 1 Jan to 31 July. Rest 15 days I stayed with friends and did not lease. From August I got a new place to rent. Unfortunately I do not have either a New York state driver's license or Washington state driver's license and hence no car

Comment: Did you do anything to tell Washington State you live there now? This also serves as proof that you are no longer a NY resident.

Comment: I have a lease agreement here in Washington. I have flight tickets to WA but not sure if that matters. I would say WA might not know that I live here but same can be said for NY

Answer (score 1):

You were physically in New York when you performed your work, therefore the services were performed in New York, and the pay from that work is considered to come from a New York source. Therefore, you are subject to New York tax on that income.